# Datagridview context menu always shows -1 in hittest

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create a context menu for a datagridview.  I had tried a few samples from here but not able to understand why the below always returns -1 for any row clicked.  This is a winforms and the grid is populated from a datatable.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
 DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgvResults.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
```

My code:

```
private void dgvResults_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {
      DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgvResults.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); \\ this shows as -1 always
      if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
      {
         dgvResults.CurrentCell = dgvResults[hit.ColumnIndex, hit.RowIndex];
         cmsResults.Show(dgvResults, e.X, e.Y);
      }
  }
}
```

When I use the MouseClick event it seem to work, I a bit lost here

```
private void dgvResults_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {
    int currentMouseOverRow = dgvResults.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
    cmsResults.Show(dgvResults, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

  }
}
```

Edit:

I finally got it to work with the below code.

Thanks to everyone

Code that worked for me:

```
private void dgvResults_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      int currentMouseOverRow = dgvResults.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
      dgvResults.ClearSelection();
      if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0) // will show Context Menu Strip if not negative
      {
          dgvResults.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Selected = true;
          cmsResults.Show(dgvResults, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
           row = currentMouseOverRow;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding the code that solved your problem to your question, post it as an answer to the question and then mark that answer as accepted. That way the question drops of the list of unanswered questions, and you can also get upvoted for the answer if others find it helpful

Comment: @DavidHall Thanks will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with the below code.

```
private void dgvResults_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {
    int currentMouseOverRow = dgvResults.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
    dgvResults.ClearSelection();
    if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0) // will show Context Menu Strip if not negative
    {
      dgvResults.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Selected = true;
      cmsResults.Show(dgvResults, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
       row = currentMouseOverRow;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at -

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/826824-invalid-coordinates-datagridview-hittest

In particular -

```
Point p = dataGridView2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y);
DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView2.HitTest(p.X, p.Y);
int row = info.RowIndex;
```

Comment: I saw that but got lost again :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour as X and Y coordinates returned by EventArgs are relative to top left corner of hosting control:

- `MouseEventArgs` return X/Y coordinates relative to `DataGridView` control.
- `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` return X/Y coordinates relative to `DataGridViewCell` control.

`HitTest` is performed against `DataGridView` control and just converts provided X/Y to Column/Row Indexes without any modifications.

Illustration below demonstrates the idea (with Blue - values returned by `MouseEventArgs`, with Green - by DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

[image]

Comment: I realized that after playing around with both and seem that MouseEventsArgs works for me.  My only concern is if the user right clicks on the columm header as I thing MouseEventsArgs cannot track that

Comment: There is no such option. Questions are closed only if they are inappropriate in any way. The only option to show your question was answered is to mark appropriate comment as answer or, if question was resolved by yourself, to explicitely specify it(like you did)